# Could not fire change event in multi select drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue. I am not able to fire the event from Angular `multiselect` drop down list. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example14data"
     selected-model="example14model" checkboxes="true"
     extra-settings="example14settings" class="form-control"
     id="specials" events="yourEvents">
</div>
```

```
$scope.yourEvents={
     onItemSelect: function(item){
         console.log("item= ", item);
     }
}
```

Here I need when user will select any item from the `dropdown` list the items should print in console which I could not. Please help me.

Comment: So, what's the error?

Comment: @digit : no error but console value is not populating.

Comment: Are you sure you have define multiselect module properly?

Comment: @digit : Yes,because i am using this module in many pages. But first time i need to fire the event and this part is only not working.

Comment: Try watch the model changes and embed it to html like this -> events="{ onItemSelect: function(item) { console.log(item) } }" .. Refer to this link https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/39